# Rotar imagen en canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

Estpy tratando de que la imagen en el canvas me quede diagonal

Esto es lo que tengo

```
 var imageObjCextrema = new Image()
  imageObjCextrema.onload = function() {
   ctx.drawImage(imageObjCextrema, 35, 250, 7, 50);
 }
  imageObjCextrema.src = 'img/cotaPT.png';
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las rotaciones no suelen ser sencillas porque dependen del centro de rotación elegido. Todo canvas tiene un 0,0 y por default este esta arriba a la izquierda. Este punto es el centro de toda rotación.

Si se desea pegar una imagen y que a su vez este rotada conviene seguir los siguientes pasos:

- `translate`: transladar el 0,0 a un punto que resulte facil manejar. El centro de donde estara puesta esta imagen es uno de ellos.
- `rotate`: rotar en un angulo en radianes el sistema de ejes x,y
- `drawImage`: pegar la imagen en el nuevo sistema de coordenadas.

```js
var papel = document.getElementById("papel");
var lapiz = papel.getContext("2d");

// Tracemos un rectangulo
lapiz.beginPath();
lapiz.moveTo(50,50);
lapiz.lineTo(200,50);
lapiz.lineTo(200,100);
lapiz.lineTo(50,100);
lapiz.closePath();
lapiz.stroke();

//Tomemos este rectangulo como source y copiemoslo en 130,150
var verticeX = 250;
var verticeY = 50;
var ancho = 170
var altura = 70;

lapiz.drawImage(papel, 40, 40, 170, 70, verticeX, verticeY, ancho, altura);

//Copiemos otro pero rotado alrededor del centro
//con "translate" corremos el 0,0 al centro del punto donde vamos a ubicar la imagen rotada
lapiz.translate(verticeX + ancho/2, verticeY + altura/2); 
//Usando "rotate" giramos los ejes en sentido horario en un angulo en radianes
lapiz.rotate(Math.PI/20);
//Pegamos la imagen en -ancho/2 y -altura/2 (el 0,0 es el centro de la imagen)
lapiz.drawImage(papel, 40, 40, 170, 70, -ancho/2, -altura/2, ancho, altura);
//Cada rotate genera un giro extra
lapiz.rotate(Math.PI/20);
lapiz.drawImage(papel, 40, 40, 170, 70, -ancho/2, -altura/2, ancho, altura);
lapiz.rotate(Math.PI/20);
lapiz.drawImage(papel, 40, 40, 170, 70, -ancho/2, -altura/2, ancho, altura);
```

```html
<canvas id="papel" width="600" height="200">
 </canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con `ctx.rotate(numeroDeRadianes)` siendo 1 vuelta entera 2pi radianes